# 'conda install' option missing in PTVS

Tags: python, visual-studio-2015, anaconda, conda, ptvs

According to [these](https://pytools.codeplex.com/releases/view/123624) release notes, installing packages via 'conda install' is supported in PTVS, which came pre-installed with my VS 2015. However, I can't seem to find how to access that option. My best guess was as follows:

1. Go to Python Environments
2. Select my Anaconda install from the left side (3.4 64-bit)
3. Select pip
4. Type a package name in the search box (waitress, for example)

When I do this, I see the option "pip install waitress" from PyPI. I'm guessing there should be another option there - "conda install waitress", but I don't see it. There is another option in the list - Install waitress. But clicking on that just performs the install via pip, not conda. I confirmed waitress is a package that's available via conda by performing "conda search waitress" from the command line.

I found [this](https://pytools.codeplex.com/workitem/2564) bug, and have confirmed the presence of the conda package and conda-meta directory in my anaconda distribution. I also opened the first JSON file in conda-meta and don't see a link to another environment.

I also found [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/issues/358) more recent issue, but it appears to just be describing adding a UI element for managing conda packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'conda install' option appears under the old UI.

See the screenshot [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/wiki/Python-Environments#managing-required-packages) and use the 'Install Python Package' option (the screenshot is highlighting something different). In that dialog, conda environments should have a 'conda' option available.

There's currently no support in Python Tools to create or automatically detect conda environments, so right now you're on your own there.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I've found to deal with this (so far) is to create the new virtual environment using conda, rather than venv (which is what PTVS seems to force).

```
conda create --name environmentName applicationPackageToInstall
```

This will create the environment in the default Anaconda environments, but you could copy it into your solution folder if you want.  From there, you can choose to use an existing environment in VS.

Note: It doesn't seem to auto-detect, so you'll need to add a new custom environment. If you do that, you can use the VS GUI to add/remove python environments.  After doing that, it's usable and the conda installer is an option via the GUI.  Alternatively, you can load the environment and do your installs from the command line.

Conda reference: http://conda.pydata.org/docs/using/envs.html#create-an-environment